# Why is string interpolation not working when constructing a href link?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The below string interpolation works fine except for the href tag.

```
html_email_body = """ 
    Hello #{username}!
    <br/>
    #{confirm_url}
    <br/>
    <a href=#{confirm_url}>confirm account2</a>        
    """
```

So this part:

```
 <a href=#{confirm_url}>confirm account2</a>
```

Is being rendered as:

```
confirm account2
```

i.e. confirm_url value is somethign like "https://www.example.com/hello/123"

Is there a problem with the equal sign and hash symbol being side by side?

Comment: Looks like the first string in your question is missing some info. Is it of this form `"Hello #{username}! <a href=#{confirm_url}>confirm account2</a>"`?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: It looks okay to me in iex: `"Hello darragh!\n<br/>\nhttps://www.example.com/hello/123\n<br/>\n<a href=https://www.example.com/hello/123>confirm account2</a>        \n"`. When you say it's being rendered as `confirm account2`—where is it being rendered like that, in an email or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

When I tried your code in iex I did get this output:

```
"<a href=https://example.com/hello/123>confirm account2</a>"
```

The only problem I can see here is that it is not valid HTML so maybe some different tool, later on, deletes it and leaves just the string here. You are missing "" around URL. So something like this should work:

```
html_email_body = """ 
    Hello #{username}!
    <br/>
    #{confirm_url}
    <br/>
    <a href="#{confirm_url}">confirm account2</a>
    """
```